# Find siblings by attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, find, siblings

I want to add a class to siblings of one *th* tag.  Those siblings have the attribute *data-sort*.  I'm trying with this code.

```
$(this).siblings('data-sort').attr('class', 'sorting');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Has Attribute Selector [name]](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/), also use [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to adds the specified class(es).

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.

```
$(this).siblings('[data-sort]').addClass('sorting');
```

Comment: I didn't explain well I was wanted to overwrite the class,  so I just changed  _addclass_for _attr_. I'll leave this code here, maybe it can help someone.  $(this).siblings('[data-sort]').attr('class', 'sorting');. Thanks for your help

Comment: What changes sholud I make in order to  add class except the siblings that have data-sort attribute?

Comment: @RohitPrabu, `$(this).siblings(':not([data-sort])').addClass('sorting');` read https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/